# Functions that return functions with parameters in Go?

Tags: go

I've done this in JS, unsure if it's possible in Go, but I'm looking to return a function as the return type from a function that has parameters.

#### Example

```
func StoreTask(db *sql.DB) func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    return func(rw, r) {
        fmt.Printf("This is the store task GET request %s", strings.Split(r.URL.Path, "/")[1])
        for _, val := range r.URL.Query() {
            fmt.Printf("Current val is: %s\n", val[0])
        }
    }
}
```

The way this would be invoked would be like the following:
`thing := StoreTask(myDb)` then I could invoke this as a handler via the HTTP library for later uses.

Comment: The only problem is that `func(rw, r) {` is not a proper function definition, because there are no types for the arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the following syntax:

```
func StoreTask(db *sql.DB) func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
  return func(wr http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("This is the store task GET request %s", strings.Split(r.URL.Path, "/")[1])
    for _, val := range r.URL.Query() {
        fmt.Printf("Current val is: %s\n", val[0])
    }
  }
}
```

Here, `StoreTask` returns a function that gets an HTTP handler, and that handler can also use the `db` argument passed into `StoreTask`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I think my main problem was I was adding variable names to the return value types in the outter function, didn't realize I can't do that.

Comment: No, the main/only problem was the _lack_ of types on the "inner" function.